# Printing links individually in Worppress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I basically want to create a category in the "Links" section of wordpress and add a number of links and titles for that category. Simple stuff.

I then want to be able to, in my template file, echo the links and title or anything about the link individually as i please. Preferably in a loop as I have some page building to do before and after the links.

I know 'category_before' and 'category_after' exist but they won't do what I need.

So I tried,

```
 <?php $args = array(
'orderby'          => 'name',
'order'            => 'ASC',
'limit'            => -1,
'category'         => '3',
'hide_invisible'   => 1,
'show_updated'     => 0,
'echo'             => 1,
'categorize'       => 0,
'category_orderby' => 'name',
'category_order'   => 'ASC',
'class'            => 'linkcat',
'category_before'  => '<tr><td>',
'category_after'   => '</td></tr>' ); 
wp_list_bookmarks( $args );
?>
```

But that does a few things wrong. I don't need the category title or anything else besides the link text and destination really.

I am hoping to have a 'for' loop that will loop all links and I can just build my code section and links inside that, but let me know if there is a better way.

Thanks

EDIT: More Info

So I tried:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'link_category'; // Taken from the DB table
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo $tax_term->name;
}
?></ul>
```

Which is the closest I have got. This only returns the info about the category not what is in the category.

There is nothing in the "wp_term_taxonomy" table in the DB about the actually category I have made.

Thanks again

EDIT:
Here is the area I'm referring to:

[I want to show these 2 links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Zu4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the `get_bookmarks` function.

```
$bookmarks = get_bookmarks( array(
    'orderby'        => 'name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'category_name'  => 'category-name'
));

// Loop through each bookmark and print formatted output
foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) { 
    printf( '<a class="relatedlink" href="%s">%s</a><br />', $bookmark->link_url, $bookmark->link_name );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

For more control you can use the function `get_terms` :

```
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'category'; // Pass default category or any custom taxonomy name
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

For info functions & its parameter:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. You have used "get_terms" but linked to "get_term". Neither return anything though. Thanks

Comment: Just went through the question again. can you provide info what is needed any references ? whats the output your expecting ?